# Tensorflow: can not convert float into a tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-recognition

I'm working on a multi-digit image recognition project, but I'm stumbling across a certain error no matter what I do.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = (None, 66, 66, 1), name = 'x')
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape = (None, 5), name = 'y')
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name = 'keep_prob')

...

with tf.Session(graph = graph) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for step in range(num_steps):
        offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
        batch_images = train_images[offset:(offset + batch_size), :, :, :]
        batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        if step % 100 == 0:
            acc = accuracy.eval(feed_dict = {x: batch_images, y: batch_labels, keep_prob: 1.0})
```

When trying to calculate `acc`, I get the error `TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Can not convert a float into a Tensor`.

I don't know why I'm getting this error. My variables are defined in the same graph and I am not overriding my variables.
Any ideas on what is causing this error?

Comment: Have you got anywhere with the `...` code public? First suspicion is that you do indeed have somewhere in your code that re-uses `x`, `y` or `keep_prob` . . . the error message is fairly specific.

Comment: @NeilSlater You're absolutely right.  I was so fixated on `x` and `y` that I forgot about `keep_prob`.  Thanks so much!